# Generating a receipt in JavaFX?

Tags: text, javafx

I want to know if my approach is correct. I am trying to display a receipt as it is being generated (You can also think of it as a dynamic text). I can only think of displaying using a 'Label'. Is there a better way? Plus, when the added text goes beyond the label size, it should become "scrollable". I tried using a 'ScrollPane' but my text just went without the scollbar "activating". I can only find 'Image's being made "scrollable" and not 'Label's or 'TextArea's. Any help or suggestion is welcome.

PS: I just started learning JavaFX 8 by trying out this application and I am unable to proceed without handling this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX resize text with window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315469/javafx-resize-text-with-window)

Comment: Putting a label in a scroll pane is probably the right approach. It's impossible to say why it's not working for you without seeing your code; can you edit the question to show what you tried?

Comment: I got my scroll pane working. Here's the code: `ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setContent(BillLabel);
        sp.setPrefSize(180,200);
        sp.setPannable(true);
        sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);`

Comment: @Barry66 You can put your comment as answer and accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to make a html template with nice styling for your receipt and use spans with unique ids .

Then using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) place your label text in that span and show that html in a webview.

One more benefit is that you can then print that receipt using [javafx8 webview printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/webview/printing.htm)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class HtmlReceipt extends Application{

String htmlTemplate = "<html>"
        + "<head>"
        + "<style>"
        + "body {background-color: yellow;}"
        + "#label1 {"
        + "background-color:red;"
        + "border:1px solid #000"
        + "}"
        + "</style>"
        + "</head>"
        + "<body>"
        + "<span id = 'label1'></span>"
        + "</body></html>";

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {   
    AnchorPane rootpane = new AnchorPane(); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootpane);
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.setPrefHeight(400);
    webView.setPrefWidth(300);
    webView.getEngine().loadContent(getReceipt("MyName"));
    rootpane.getChildren().add(webView);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public String getReceipt(String labelText){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlTemplate);
    Element span = doc.select("span#label1").first();
    span.text(labelText);
    return doc.html();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems like a very heavyweight approach when you could just use a `Label` or a `Text` in a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: I agree with @James_D. Your solution seems a bit heavy, though presentable.